# Reducing duplication between custom Saltstack states

Tags: salt-stack, opensuse, podman

I am writing custom Saltstack states for applications running as podman containers and I see lots of duplication between those, since they all need:

- a customer user/group
- a data directory
- a configuration directory
- a backup directory
- a systemd unit generated by `podman generate systemd`

  - a trigger to reload systemd when the service file changes
- an env file for the `systemd` unit
- a systemd unit and timer for the backup

Previously those would be mostly handled by RPM packages, but with Saltstack it is up to me and it's quite verbose.

I know about parameterised states + pillars but I don't like that because I would get generic `podman` states plus a lot of if/else which would make it hard to read. I think SaltStack formulas are the same technical solution but designed upfront to be reusable.

I am not a Python programmer so I did not go down the route for custom modules.

Are there any other options to create reusable Saltstack custom states?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a lot of if/else. You just use a map.

Then the simplest way of passing which map to use, is via a Jinja2 `include` and the [`sls*` variables](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/vars.html).

```yaml
# salt/app1/init.sls

{% include common/states.sls %}

more specific state:
  foo.whatever:
    - name: something
    - require:
      - app1 data directory
```

```yaml
# salt/app1/defaults.yaml

name: &NAME app1
user: *NAME 
group: *NAME
data_dir: *NAME
conf_dir: *NAME
env:
  FOO: 1

# ...
```

```yaml
# salt/common/states.sls

{% from common/map.jinja import data with context %}

{{ data["name"] }} group:
  group.present:
    - name: {{ data["group"] }}

{{ data["name"] }} user:
  user.present:
    - name: {{ data["user"] }}
    - groups: [ {{ data["group"] }} ]
    - require:
      - {{ data["name"] }} group

{{ data["name"] }} data directory:
  file.directory:
    - name: /var/lib/{{ data["datadir"] }}
    - user: {{ data["user"] }}
    - group: {{ data["group"] }}
    - mode: '0750'
    - require:
      - {{ data["name"] }} user
      - {{ data["name"] }} group

# ...
```

```py
# salt/common/map.jinja

{% import_yaml slspath ~ "/defaults.yaml" as defaults %}
{% set overrides = salt["config.get"](slscolonpath) %}
{% set data = salt["slsutil.update"](defaults, overrides) %}
```

```yaml
# pillar/minion-6.sls
app1:
  group: shared-apps
  env:
    FOO: 0
    BAR: 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the post - I'm going to need a bit of time to unwrap, some things are unfamiliar to me.

_Edit_: I think this creates a common state that can be parameterised and then imported into multiple app states, with overrides based on pillars. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. It's parametrised states and pillars, with not a single `if`. Except you don't really need overrides, because your parameters are based on what app it is, not what minion it's on.